# MonoTouch - Running in Debug results in "Could not insert pending Breakpoint"

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've done a CLEAN ALL, I've reset the simulator, but I can't explain why I get the following: (see the 'Resolved pending breakpoint' line, and the 'Could not insert')

```
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/drisszouak/Projects/ZenVelopes/ZenVelopes/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/ZenVelopes.exe
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'EnvelopeViewController.xib.cs:76' to Void ZenVelopes.EnvelopeViewController:HandleBtnNewEnvelopeClicked ():0.
Could not insert pending breakpoint at 'EnvelopeViewController.xib.cs:69'. Perhaps the source line does not contain any statements, or the source does not correspond to the current binary.
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll [External]
```

The code on line 69 and 76 are valid code, and are event handlers for toolbar buttons. Then when I click on one of the buttons, I get a null reference exception.

Comment: Please file a bug in the monotouch bugtracker with a sample applicaiton which shows this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem 'went away' after fixing another, seemingly completely unrelated problem.